# C#. How to programmatically grant User Log On as a Service

Tags: c#, windows, local-security-policy

I've searched through the internet, but haven't found any solution in c#. Does anybody know how to give user right to log on as a Service in c#?

Comment: found it on this stack question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891623/c-sharp-granting-log-on-as-service-permission-to-a-windows-user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: I found an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/lsadotnet.aspx) on CodeProject with sample code that shows exactly how to do this!

I assume you've already found [this KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/132958) that shows how to do it with native code.  I'm looking for a C# way as well.

Answer (score -1):

I tried in vain to find this. The way I did it in the end was to package the NTRights executable with my application and then launch it as a separate process.

NTRights can be found on the server 2003 resource kti and its usage is documented here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315276

Comment: Yeah, thanks I did the same thing but wanna find the way to do it through some API or...