# c# Granting "Log On As Service" permission to a windows user

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

how do I grant a user the LogOnAsService right for a service?

I need to do this manually, in the *services.msc* app I can go to the service, change the password (setting the same that there was before), click apply and I get a message:

> The account .\postgres has been
>   granted the Log On As Service right.

How do I do this from code, because otherwise I have to give this permission by hand each time I run the application and this is not a possibility

@Steve

```
    static void Main()
    {
        // irrelevant stuff

        GrantLogonAsServiceRight("postgres");

        // irrelevant stuff
    }

    private static void GrantLogonAsServiceRight(string username)
    {
        using (LsaWrapper lsa = new LsaWrapper())
        {
            lsa.AddPrivileges(username, "SeServiceLogonRight");
        }
    }
```

and the LSA lib by this guy Willy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [Granting User Rights in C#](http://weblogs.asp.net/avnerk/archive/2007/05/10/granting-user-rights-in-c.aspx).

You have to invoke the LSA APIs via P/Invoke, and that URL has a reference to a [wrapper class](https://web.archive.org/web/20151218044501/http://www.hightechtalks.com/csharp/lsa-functions-276626.html) that does that for you.  So the code you end up with is simple:

```
private static void GrantLogonAsServiceRight(string username)
{
   using (LsaWrapper lsa = new LsaWrapper())
   {
      lsa.AddPrivileges(username, "SeServiceLogonRight");
   }
}
```

Comment: sounds great, but I get Win32UnhandledException: The parameter is incorrect

Comment: @Nico - where inside the LSAWrapper do you get the exception?  Can you use 'domain\\name' instead?

Comment: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done, anyways I was getting the Sid, the exception was at the end of the AddPrivileges() function: throw new Win32Exception(Win32Sec.LsaNtStatusToWinError((int)ret));

Comment: @Nico - I am getting exactly the same error, did you figure out a fix?

Comment: Mark posted this comment: "You need to remove the 'domain\' part and only put the username. It can't find the security ID unless it is just the username by itself." @galets: This may be relevant to you.