# How do I check/grant logon as service rights in a 64bit environment

Tags: c#

I am running into a wall with the whole p/invoke issue.  I need to do this programmatically in C#.

Comment: Ive tried using the LSA wrapper floating around out there, can be seen in the following 2 links:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286795/c-how-to-programmatically-grant-user-log-on-as-a-service

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4863/LSA-Functions-Privileges-and-Impersonation

I have also tried the method listed in the next link.  It will show users who belong to each group policy, but this doesn't help me if the user is a member of a group with LSA, because the user wouldnt be listed.  

http://david-homer.blogspot.com/2012/03/audit-and-document-security-user-rights.html

Comment: Sorry, let me know if the last comment helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the p/invoke stuff (with the LSA wrapper) a couple of weeks ago. I got an exception the first time I run the wrapper, but it succeeded the second time on Win2k8 server 64 bit.

Something like this worked for me

```
try{
   DoThePInvokeMagic();
}
catch(Exception){
    // Sometimes the first invocation fails, but the second time it seems to work       
    DoThePInvokeMagic();
}
```

Unfortunately we did not have time/prio to investigate further why this happened and why it worked the second time, since we got it working on all our servers.

Comment: Wow.  You're right, it fails on first try and passes on second.  I am grateful for that tip.  I will spend some time trying to figure out why and hopefully get back to you.

Comment: One thing I did different is avoided the recursion and added an error counter.  Im thinking that if there was some other error in the LSA/PInvoke code you would hit an endless loop.  Check this out:
`catch(Exception ex) 
            {
                errorCount = errorCount + 1;
                if (errorCount > 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                else
                {
                    goto restart;
                }
            }
`